# How should I test this Java API with a Multipart File as a RequestParam

Tags: java, unit-testing, model-view-controller, junit

I am trying to test the following API on the Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/{code}")
public ResponseEntity<RefInterneImportDTO> importFichier(@PathVariable("code") String code,
                                                         @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(refInterneImportService.importFichier(code, file));
}
```

I am trying to test this API through Cucumber/JUnit

```
 @Quand("On appelle refInterneImportController.importer pour importer un fichier {string}")
public void On_appelle_refinterne_import_controller_importer_pour_importer_un_fichier(String nomFichier) {
    try {
        file = new MockMultipartFile(nomFichier, nomFichier, "multipart/form-data",
            new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/templates/" + nomFichier));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    String urlTemplate = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(URL_REF_INTERNE_IMPORT).path("/" + dto.code()).toUriString();
    REST_TEMPLATE.postForObject(urlTemplate, file, RefInterneImportDTO.class);
}
```

However, whenever I call the API through REST_TEMPLATE I get:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream]
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
> No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile["inputStream"])

I already tried to disable this serialization feature but nothing happened. I know that some people will probably suggesting changing my API signature to accept an array of bytes instead of a `MultipartFile`, however, isn't sending an array of bytes less secure than a `MultipartFile`.
I also tried building a custom `HttpEntity` and no can do.